# Webpack fails to mount Vue components

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component

After using Webpack with Vue to compile a project, when I open a page that uses a Vue component I get:

> `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

and in place of the component Vue renders

```
<-- function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); } -->
```

Why does this error happen?

Note: [I've created an MCVE for this problem.](https://gist.github.com/RedHatter/8eadc65bd5f8327f26dcfd10a7bf3dad) The exact Webpack config used is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/display.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [ { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `const Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.common.js')` to `const Vue = require('vue')`. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/713 and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only for details.

Comment: That causes `Vue is not a constructor`.  I've tried all the files in `dist` as well, none of them work.

Comment: Have you considered starting with one of the default templates via `vue-cli`? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply due to [change of vue-loader](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-loader-with-webpack-not-supporting-commonjs-require/15014/4).

> Since version 13.0.0, vue-loader doesn’t normalize exports anymore. You have to do
>   `const app =  require('./app.vue').default`

So just change `Child: require('./child.vue')` in your `display.js` to `Child: require('./child.vue').default` and then it will work.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if this works when I'm back in the office on Monday.

Comment: This worked for me! Easily changed inside the `Vue.component()` function as well: `Vue.component('test', require('../components/Test.vue').default);`

Answer (score 3):

I know it it's old, but someone might run into this problem.

Try adding resolve alias to your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    }
  }
}
```

more about this:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using [snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/).

I stumbled upon this question while trying to solve the problem I had, so I guess if anyone is in the same sitiation I was in this might help:

I was using [`vue 2.6.12`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) with `Import Vue from 'vue'`. Like proposed by [żyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5578846/%c5%bcyy) I added an alias

```js
alias: {
        'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
```

to `snowpack.config.js`. This however doesnt quite fix it yet. Im not sure why this doesn't work, but I think it has to do with the fact that snowpack applys the alias after bundling. So you need to force snowpack to also bundle `vue/dist/vue.esm.j`, which I did by creating a dummy file in my project that will also get bundled:

```js
// _.js:
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js';

let _ = new Vue();
```

I wouldn't call this a perfect solution, so feel free to suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the location of files. I keep my files in this style

```
ListItem.ts
ListItem.vue
ListItem.scss
index.ts
```

Problem was I didn't have the files in a `list-item` directory and was just importing like `import ListItem from './components/ListItem';` Moving them in the directory and updating the import to `./compoents/list-item` fixed my issue.

One of those darn copy-pasta errors that get ya every time.